# PHP redirection issue

Tags: php

I have a program that prints reports for a user id list. The program is supposed to print reports one by one for users on the list uploaded. The problem is that when I was running the printing process and getting to print the report with indexInList=30, I got error:

> This webpage has a redirect loop
>   The webpage at http://127.0.0.1/content/8520?print=1&bulkprinting=1&filename=/private/var/tmp/phpHRXEw8.moved&indexInList=30&nopeergroup=1&nolabpage=0&hideScreeningOnly=1&showOnlyScreening=0&hideHoldMailing=1 has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

I tried to clean the cookie but still keep getting the same error.

I attached some code here and hope anyone can help me:

```
  $sessionData['first_name'] = $foundUser->first_name;
  $sessionData['last_name']  = $foundUser->last_name;

  // Overwrite $_REQUEST variable with parameters before including
  // the hpa report
  $_REQUEST = array(
    'user_id'      => $foundUser->id,
    'bulkprinting' => true
  );
  if($nopeergroup) { $_REQUEST['nopeergroup'] = $nopeergroup; }
  if($nolabpage) { $_REQUEST['nolabpage'] = $nolabpage; }
  if($hideScreeningOnly) { $_REQUEST['hideScreeningOnly'] = $hideScreeningOnly; }
  if($showOnlyScreening) { $_REQUEST['showOnlyScreening'] = $showOnlyScreening; }
  if($hideHoldMailing) { $_REQUEST['hideHoldMailing'] = $hideHoldMailing; }

  $includeValue = include __DIR__.'/../hpa/hpa.php';

  $url = sprintf(
    "/content/8520?print=1&bulkprinting=1&filename=%s&indexInList=%s" .
    "&nopeergroup=%s&nolabpage=%s&hideScreeningOnly=%s" .
    "&showOnlyScreening=%s&hideHoldMailing=%s",
    $filename, $indexInList, (int)$nopeergroup, (int)$nolabpage,
    (int)$hideScreeningOnly, (int)$showOnlyScreening, (int)$hideHoldMailing);

  if($hradata[0] !== false) {
    $sessionData['hra_id'] = $hradata[0]['id'];
  }
  if($screeningdata[0] !== false) {
    $sessionData['screening_id'] = $screeningdata[0]['id'];
  }

  if($includeValue !== 1) {
    // Redirect to URL
    $sessionData['message']     = $messages_set[$includeValue];
    $_SESSION['printing_set'][] = $sessionData;

    redirect($url);
  }

  $sessionData['markAsMailed'] = true;
  $_SESSION['printing_set'][]  = $sessionData;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function waitPrint() {
    window.print();
    var t = setTimeout("timed()", 1000);
  }
  function timed() {
    window.location.replace("<?php echo $url ?>");
  }

  if(window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onload", waitPrint);
  } else if(window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", waitPrint, false);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a lot of files that need printing!

You may be able to alter your browser settings (I seem to remember you can in Firefox) to allow more than 30 loops.

Alternatively, you could always limit your code to 30 loops then wait for further user interaction to proceed to the next 30.

The 3rd option is to always create a Word document or PDF with one report on each page, then save the file and print it - a little more hassle (in a way) but at least you'll be able to print everything at once.

Answer (score 0):

In order for `$includeValue` to be set to anything, the file `__DIR__.'/../hpa/hpa.php'` must have a return statement inside of it, as demonstrated in the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) for `include`, example 5. `include` will only return a value when called if the included file returns a value.

If your script still produces an infinite loop, your logic within the included file is incorrect and it is consistently producing a value that is not `1`.

Essentially, here is the code that your question boils down to:

```
$includeValue = include __DIR__.'/../hpa/hpa.php';
if($includeValue !== 1) {
    // Redirect
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Do you know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers have checks built-in to help you when sites are misconfigured into a redirection loop, and 30 must be the limit for the browser you're using. You've built a redirection loop on purpose, but the browser doesn't know that. Instead of using the `window.location.replace()` method, how about a form that automatically submits? That should look different to the browser, and allow your loop to progress as designed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function waitPrint() {
    window.print();
    var t = setTimeout("timed()", 1000);
  }
  function timed() {
    window.reloadForm.submit();
  }
  if(window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onload", waitPrint);
  } else if(window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", waitPrint, false);
  }
</script>

<form name="reloadForm" action="<?php echo $url ?>">
</form>
```